# Multiple databinding to a Datalist ASP.net VB or C#

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datalist

I wanna show some values of variables (about 6) inside item template of a Datalist. let's say if i have

```
     Dim A As String = "hello world"
```

I wanna show that inside the Datalist. Dim A needs to be declared on Page Load or in a method  somewhere .. coz the source is the database,so i can't just declare as public const on the top of the page.

I tried this in Datalist but i won't work as expected.

```
     <%= a %>
```

I also tried putting that different places like ItemDataBound or Page init. it won't work if the way i did was wrong.

In the datasource of Datalist is a datatable with other data. So it is like i am having more than one source for Datalist. Is there any way around other than putting that Dim A inside the datatable?

Thanks Lau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put as a variable in the class (and assign the value in page load if needed)

```
Public A As string = "hello world"
```

Then in the DataList template field use:

```
<%# A %>
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus .. that simply works ... I was confused between <%= var %> vs <%# var %>